# Get parameters of the POST request with ZK Framework

Tags: java, post, zk

I want to pass data from one application (Spring MVC) to another application written with ZK Framework using **POST** request.
One of the parameters of the post method will be a file. Let's call it `id`.

So, what I do have now is ***Composer*** with the following code:

```
public class PictureComposer extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        Execution e = Executions.getCurrent();

        System.out.println("post param: " + Executions.getCurrent().getParameterMap().get("id"));

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) e.getNativeRequest();
        String idd = request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println("id: " + idd);
    }
}
```

And, when I try to make a **POST** request to this composer, `Executions.getCurrent().getParameterMap().get("id")` seems to return `null`.

Same thing with the second approach (using `HttpServletRequest`).

On the other hand, I get some value for `id`, when I use ***GET*** request and pass this value as a parameter in the URL. But, unfortunately, I cannot pass my file in the URL.

So, the main question is how I can retrieve the variable from the **POST** request?

**UPD:** (for now I try to retrieve a plain string parameter, just as simplified example) My ***POST*** request looks like this:

```
POST /zssessentials/picture.zul HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

wooooow
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Comment: How are you sending the file to this URL? Are you trying with multipart mime type?

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam I've updated the question and added the content of POST request. Please, take a look.

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553493/zk-zul-get-value-from-input-form-data) having problems with executions and POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out.

The reason was that the servlet didn't parse the multipart requests on its own.
I had been sending requests with this line in the header (even if it was plain string or integer values):

`Content-type: multipart/form-data`

and that was the reason.

So, I was expected to use the third-party library in the `PictureComposer` class.

In my case [Streaming API from  Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) came in handy.

Also, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337115/1114934) helped me a lot in resolving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve an uploaded file, you should set `enctype` property of your `<form>` element to `multipart/form-data`, as below:

```
<form method="POST" action="your/zk/address" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    ...
</form>
```

Then you can use the `getPart` method of `HttpServletRequest` class to access the uploaded file. So your code should be changed to something like this:

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("id");
InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `filePart` becomes `null` here.